# Call a simple javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, insertafter

I have this code where I insert a read more link after a label with a specific ID:

```
$( "<a class='readMore' href='/moreByggherre' id='moreByggherre'>Läs mer</a>" ).insertAfter( $("label[for='Byggherre']") );
```

The above code works, but since I will be doing this a lot I would like to have a function which just takes the ID and outputs the html code with inserAfter.

I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
createReadMoreBtn('Byggherre');
function createReadMoreBtn($id){
    $insertTxt = "<a class='readMore' href='/more".$id."' id='more".$id."'>Läs mer</a>";
    $( $insertTxt ).insertAfter( $("label[for='".$id."']") );
}
```

Comment: What HTML are you starting with? I *think* you're using the [`<label>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) incorrectly (a `<label>` is supposed to identify a specific form element (such as `<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` and so on) rather than merely serving to 'label' arbitrary content on the page, but without context it's very hard to say for sure, *or* offer better more useful methods to do as you ask.

Comment: I use the `<label>` since I want the Read more button to be inserted next to the title, which works. I used `<input>` before, but it didn't work. My problem was that I used `.` for concatenation instead of `+`.

Comment: Explaining your code doesn't help as much as showing your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not PHP to use `.` for concatenation instead, you need to use `+` for concatenation in JavaScript.

```
createReadMoreBtn('Byggherre');

function createReadMoreBtn($id)
{
    $insertTxt = "<a class='readMore' href='/more" + $id + "' id='more" + $id + "'>Läs mer</a>";
    $( $insertTxt ).insertAfter( $("label[for='" + $id + "']") );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this;

```
 createReadMoreBtn('Byggherre');

    function createReadMoreBtn($id)
    {
        $insertTxt = "<a class='readMore' href='/more"+$id+"' id='more"+$id+"'>Läs mer</a>";
        $( $insertTxt ).insertAfter( $("label[for='"+$id+"']") );
    }
```

Comment: Yes it works with +, but need it on both sides of $id, not just on the left.